# how to create a javascript object without double quotes on the property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

From this data

```
[{"lat":"-1.325416","lng":"36.669051"},
 {"lat":"-1.392932","l‌​ng":"36.768752"},
 {"l‌​at":"-1.390505","lng‌​":"36.810023"},
 {"lat‌​":"-1.448266","lng":‌​"36.952769"},
 {"lat":‌​"-1.267033","lng":"3‌​7.094882"},
 {"lat":"-‌​1.214605","lng":"37.‌​053978"},
 {"lat":"-1.‌​169516","lng":"36.89‌​5608"}]
```

I am trying to create a javascript object that looks like this.

```
 var outerCoords =[
          {lat: -1.325416, lng: 36.669051},
          {lat: -1.392932, lng: 36.768752},
          {lat: -1.390505, lng: 36.810023},
          {lat: -1.448266, lng: 36.952769},
          {lat: -1.267033, lng: 37.094882},
          {lat: -1.214605, lng: 37.053978}, 
          {lat: -1.169516, lng: 36.895608},
          {lat: -1.244058, lng: 36.730391}
        ],
```

the property value without double quotes. 
I have first, stringified my json to get a string, then removed the double quotes from the string, then parsed the result with no double quotes. Parsing the result does not create an object, it returns a string. Please if you can help i'll appreciate. 
This is what am doing.

```
var str= JSON.stringify(outercords1); 
var x = str.replace (/"/g,'');
var obj= JSON.parse(x);
```

the value of outercords is:

```
[{"lat":"-1.325416","lng":"36.669051"},{"lat":"-1.392932","lng":"36.768752"},{"lat":"-1.390505","lng":"36.810023"},{"lat":"-1.448266","lng":"36.952769"},{"lat":"-1.267033","lng":"37.094882"},{"lat":"-1.214605","lng":"37.053978"},{"lat":"-1.169516","lng":"36.895608"}]
```

Comment: please add the raw data, you have.

Comment: JSON requires double quotes, except for in a few data types, like Number and Bool. If you're parsing the object you'll have access to the value, without quotes.

Comment: Could you post the value of `outercords1`?

Comment: [{"lat":"-1.325416","lng":"36.669051"},{"lat":"-1.392932","lng":"36.768752"},{"lat":"-1.390505","lng":"36.810023"},{"lat":"-1.448266","lng":"36.952769"},{"lat":"-1.267033","lng":"37.094882"},{"lat":"-1.214605","lng":"37.053978"},{"lat":"-1.169516","lng":"36.895608"}]

Comment: Are you sure they are numbers in the original object because if they are then they won't be quoted (just tested it)

Comment: You can pass a second parametter to [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (a function that will be called on all the key-value pairs) and then transform string that represent valid numbers to numbers: `var str= JSON.stringify(outercords1, function(key, value) { if(isNaN(value)) return value; else return Number(value); });`

Comment: that will return a string and not an object

Comment: Ibrahim, i have saved the values as doubles in the database, how do i  pass them as numbers in my json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think don't use `stringify` that solve your problem try it as it is.

Comment: i have tried without stringify and this is what am getting if i try access the object                                                                                                      Object { lat: "-1.325416", lng: "36.669051" }

Comment: now access it like an arrays such as object[0].lat i am not sure it works or not

Comment: obj[0].lat
"-1.325416" this is the output

Comment: well  check that if you use  number(long) to save lat and lag that make a big difference add it as number to json

Comment: i used this  json_encode($result,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); to convert the lat/lons to numbers and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Stringified JSON has quoted properties. This is mandatory. So a javascript object in the form

```
var outerCoords =[
      {lat: -1.325416, lng: 36.669051},
      {lat: -1.392932, lng: 36.768752},
      {lat: -1.390505, lng: 36.810023},
      {lat: -1.448266, lng: 36.952769},
      {lat: -1.267033, lng: 37.094882},
      {lat: -1.214605, lng: 37.053978}, 
      {lat: -1.169516, lng: 36.895608},
      {lat: -1.244058, lng: 36.730391}
    ],
```

Will be stringified as

```
'[{"lat":-1.325416,"lng":36.669051},{"lat":-1.392932,"lng":36.768752},{"lat":-1.390505,"lng":36.810023},{"lat":-1.448266,"lng":36.952769},{"lat":-1.267033,"lng":37.094882},{"lat":-1.214605,"lng":37.053978},{"lat":-1.169516,"lng":36.895608},{"lat":-1.244058,"lng":36.730391}]'
```

removing the quotes will turn it invalid to be parsed as JSON, so that's why you're getting a string.

On the other hand, performing

```
JSON.parse('[{"lat":-1.325416,"lng":36.669051},{"lat":-1.392932,"lng":36.768752},{"lat":-1.390505,"lng":36.810023},{"lat":-1.448266,"lng":36.952769},{"lat":-1.267033,"lng":37.094882},{"lat":-1.214605,"lng":37.053978},{"lat":-1.169516,"lng":36.895608},{"lat":-1.244058,"lng":36.730391}]');
```

Will give you an object. The same object you hand when you begun.

Object properties are always casted as strings, so declaring your object as

```
var outerCoords =[
  {"lat": -1.325416, "lng": 36.669051},
  {"lat": -1.392932, "lng": 36.768752},
  {"lat": -1.390505, "lng": 36.810023},
  {"lat": -1.448266, "lng": 36.952769},
  {"lat": -1.267033, "lng": 37.094882},
  {"lat": -1.214605, "lng": 37.053978}, 
  {"lat": -1.169516, "lng": 36.895608},
  {"lat": -1.244058, "lng": 36.730391}
];
```

is the same as declaring it without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var outerCoords =[
    {lat: -1.325416, lng: 36.669051},
    {lat: -1.392932, lng: 36.768752},
    {lat: -1.390505, lng: 36.810023},
    {lat: -1.448266, lng: 36.952769},
    {lat: -1.267033, lng: 37.094882},
    {lat: -1.214605, lng: 37.053978}, 
    {lat: -1.169516, lng: 36.895608},
    {lat: -1.244058, lng: 36.730391}
]
        
var str= JSON.stringify(outerCoords); 
//var x = str.replace (/"/g,'');
var obj= JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterating the array and the objects and convert all stringed numbers to number.

The keys have, according to the [JSON](http://json.org/), always double quotes.

```js
 var outerCoords = [{ "lat": "-1.325416", "lng": "36.669051" }, { "lat": "-1.392932", "lng": "36.768752" }, { "lat": "-1.390505", "lng": "36.810023" }, { "lat": "-1.448266", "lng": "36.952769" }, { "lat": "-1.267033", "lng": "37.094882" }, { "lat": "-1.214605", "lng": "37.053978" }, { "lat": "-1.169516", "lng": "36.895608" }];

outerCoords.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (isFinite(o[k])) {
            o[k] = +o[k];
        }
    });
});

console.log(outerCoords);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: getting a typeError

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) with a custom `reviver` function to manipulate your elements.

```js
var outderCoords1=[{"lat":"-1.325416","lng":"36.669051"},
 {"lat":"-1.392932","lng":"36.768752"}];

var outerCoords = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(outderCoords1), 
   function(name, value) {
   if(!(typeof value.replace === "undefined")){
       var v= parseFloat(value.replace(/"/g, ""));
            alert(typeof(v));
           } 
        });
```

Comment: This is the response it gives..[{'lat':'-1.325416','lng':'36.669051'},{'lat':'-1.392932','lng':'36.768752'},{'lat':'-1.390505','lng':'36.810023'},{'lat':'-1.448266','lng':'36.952769'},{'lat':'-1.267033','lng':'37.094882'},{'lat':'-1.214605','lng':'37.053978'},{'lat':'-1.169516','lng':'36.895608'}]

Comment: I have given u idea, u can put your transformation logic

Comment: i meant to say it does not output an object. it outputs a string

Comment: Parse return object, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: @Lizbeth, we can use parseFloat to convert string to number after removing quotes, refer updated answer.